# Intuition of the regression model under fixed design case (nonparametric regression)

Tags: experiment-design, asymptotics, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-regression

Let $(x_1,Y_1), \dotsc, (x_n,Y_n)$ be a random sample from the regression model
$$Y_t=m(x_t)+\epsilon_t.$$
When authors want to develop the asymptotic properties of the local linear estimator of $m$ when the design points are fixed (for example, $x_t=t/n$), they usually assume things that I don't really undersand. [Fan and Gijbels](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d89/0548efbd8e44518db3517349f56c7eb18319.pdf) Assumed the design density $f$ satisfies
$$x_j=G^{-1}(j/n) \text{ with } G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y)dy.$$

[Fernandez](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265330770_Local_polynomial_regression_estimation_with_correlated_errors) Assumed that the regular design density satisfies 
$$\int_0^{x_t}f(y)dy=\frac{t-1}{n-1}, 1\leq t\leq n. $$

Does anyone understand what is the intuition behind it? Why the design points are defined in terms of cumulative distribution functions?

*I will print the relevant parts of their papers:

**Fan**

[image]

**Fernandez**

[image]

Comment: It's interesting, when pondering this question, to consider what alternative approaches there might be.  Since you're studying asymptotics, you have to supply some way to produce a sequence of $x$ values for each $n.$  Clearly whatever your procedure might be, it has to allow the sequences to vary (because their lengths vary!).  What would you propose?

Comment: @whuber Nice comment. For Fernandez procedure, I see that $P(x_{t-1,n}\leq X\leq x_{t,n} )=1/(n-1)$. So, given the density $f_X$, the distance between $x_{t-1,n}$ and $x_{t,n}$ must be $O(1/n)$. I think this is a good way to start thinking the model. That is, when $n$ grows, the regular design points become "dense". And this is what the asymptotics requires, in this case.